# How to access data from res.render in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to access the data that was sent from response.render in my html file.

I have this code in my server.

```
 app.post('/game',function(req,res){
 var name = "Jude";
 res.render(__dirname +'/game.html',{user:name});
 });
```

How do i access user variable in my game.html?

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to use a template language like [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade), [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) and [so on](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-templating). If you already have the HTML in place, try EJS.